# Django: create object from CSV that has a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I've 2 models: `Category` and `Product`, and I need to upload both from CSVs files.

I can do that when uploading CSV data for the `Category` model, as it does not have a ForeignKey field.

But I get an error when trying to upload data from a CSV fro the `Product` model. As it has a ForeignKey to the Category model.

> ValueError: Cannot assign "'Stickers'": "Product.category" must be a
>   "Category" instance.

Is it possible? I could leave the field as blank and not requeried to do this manually later, but woudl be ideal to do this automatically.

**commands/products.py**:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from shop.models import Product
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


tmp_data_products=pd.read_csv('static/data/products.csv',sep=',', encoding="utf-8").fillna(" ")


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        products = [
            Product(
                category=row['category'],
                product=row['product'],
                slug=row['slug'],
                description=row['description'],
                size=row['size'],
                quantity =row['quantity'],
                price=row['image'],
                available=row['available']
        )
            for _, row in tmp_data_products.iterrows()
        ]

        Product.objects.bulk_create(products)
```

**models.py:**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category', blank=True, null=True)
    video = EmbedVideoField(null=True, blank=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TAMANIOS)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CANTIDADES)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product', blank=True, null=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**UPDATE 1:**

**categories.csv**

```
| category  | slug      | description                                                          | image | video |
|-----------|-----------|----------------------------------------------------------------------|-------|-------|
| Imantados | imantados | Los mejores imantados en vinyl,   acabado mate. Resistentes al agua. |       |       |
| Stickers  | stickers  | Los mejores stickers en vinyl,   acabado mate. Resistentes al agua.  |       |       |
| Muestras  | muestras  | Los mejores stickers en vinyl,   acabado mate. Resistentes al agua.  |       |       |
```

**products.csv**

```
| category | product                | slug                   | description                                                           | size      | quantity | price | image | available |
|----------|------------------------|------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------|----------|-------|-------|-----------|
| Stickers | Stickers transparentes | stickers-transparentes | Stickers Transparentes en Vinyl de alta calidad. Resistentes al agua. | 5cm x 5cm | 50       | 50    |       | True      |
| Stickers | Stickers transparentes | stickers-transparentes | Stickers Transparentes en Vinyl de alta calidad. Resistentes al agua. | 5cm x 5cm | 100      | 70    |       | True      |
| Stickers | Stickers transparentes | stickers-transparentes | Stickers Transparentes en Vinyl de alta calidad. Resistentes al agua. | 5cm x 5cm | 200      | 90    |       | True      |
| Stickers | Stickers transparentes | stickers-transparentes | Stickers Transparentes en Vinyl de alta calidad. Resistentes al agua. | 5cm x 5cm | 300      | 120   |       | True      |
| Stickers | Stickers transparentes | stickers-transparentes | Stickers Transparentes en Vinyl de alta calidad. Resistentes al agua. | 5cm x 5cm | 500      | 140   |       | True      |
| Stickers | Stickers transparentes | stickers-transparentes | Stickers Transparentes en Vinyl de alta calidad. Resistentes al agua. | 5cm x 5cm | 1000     | 200   |       | True      |
| Stickers | Stickers transparentes | stickers-transparentes | Stickers Transparentes en Vinyl de alta calidad. Resistentes al agua. | 5cm x 5cm | 2000     | 300   |       | True      |
| Stickers | Stickers transparentes | stickers-transparentes | Stickers Transparentes en Vinyl de alta calidad. Resistentes al agua. | 7cm x 7cm | 50       | 70    |       | True      |
| Stickers | Stickers transparentes | stickers-transparentes | Stickers Transparentes en Vinyl de alta calidad. Resistentes al agua. | 7cm x 7cm | 100      | 90    |       | True      |
| Stickers | Stickers transparentes | stickers-transparentes | Stickers Transparentes en Vinyl de alta calidad. Resistentes al agua. | 7cm x 7cm | 200      | 130   |       | True      |
```

Comment: how is your csv file structured? What do you have in row['category']?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the error says, you have to get the corresponding object from the db first in order to be able to assign it:

```
category = Category.objects.get(id=row['category'])
```

There's a shortcut however:

```
category_id = row['category']
```

Mind the `_id` which allows you to assign the foreign key (= the primary key of the referred object) directly.

When using this, you obviously won't notice an invalid foreign key until writing the object to the database.

---

If you really have category names rather than ids in your CSV file, then you definitely need to locate the corresponding database object first:

```
category = Category.objects.get(category=row['category'])
```

You could wrap this in a try/except to prepare for missing categories; thankfully there's a unique constraint on the category name, so multiple objects with the same name won't be an issue.

Comment: I think he has category names in in the csv file: "Cannot assign "'Stickers'": "Product.category" must be a "Category" instance."

Comment: Is it possible to pass the field/s at runtime? For example in the OP's function `handle(...`, the field mapping `category_id = row['category'],  
  product=row['product'],   ...` be built into a list and then used in place of each and every one of the fields mapped (as in the said function)?